# problem while generating pdf files using iText 5

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, pdf-generation, itext

i'm trying to generat pdf files using iText, i want those files to be opened directly on my chrome browser so here is my print method's code:

```
 public void printFicheProjet()
    {
        Integer id=Integer.valueOf((String)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("id_projet_print"));
        Projets projet=projetsService.getProjets(id);
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        try {
            HttpServletResponse hsr = (HttpServletResponse) context.getExternalContext().getResponse();
            hsr.setContentType("application/pdf");
            hsr.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=\"enseignants.pdf\"");
            Document pdf = new Document(PageSize.A4, 5, 5, 5, 5);
            pdf.setPageSize(PageSize.A4);
            pdf.addHeader("Banque Centrale Populaire", "Fiche Projet");
            ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            PdfWriter.getInstance(pdf, os);
            pdf.open();            
            Font font = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12, Font.NORMAL);
            Paragraph p = new Paragraph("", font);
            p = new Paragraph("Informations genereaux du projet", font);
            Font gras = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12, Font.BOLD);
            p.setIndentationLeft(30);
            pdf.add(p);
            pdf.close();
            byte[] data = os.toByteArray();
            hsr.getOutputStream().write(data);
            context.responseComplete();
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
```

the problem is when i execute this method nothing happens, no error no file on the browser no downloading window...completly nothing. may be something is missing there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the `commandbutton` should have `ajax="false"` attribute and it should work fine.
Instead of:

```
<p:commandButton value="Imprimer Fiche Projet" actionListener="#{projet.printFicheProjet}">
    <f:param name="id_projet_print" value="#{projet.currentChangerStatus.projets.codeProjet}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

Put:

```
<p:commandButton value="Imprimer Fiche Projet" actionListener="#{projet.printFicheProjet}" ajax="false">
    <f:param name="id_projet_print" value="#{projet.currentChangerStatus.projets.codeProjet}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

Comment: worked for me!
could anyboby explain why this is not working with ajax? @cascadox

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing

```
  catch (Exception e) {}
```

with

```
    catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace()
}
```

Which should print the exception being thrown to console.

Comment: i debuged the method and it was executed till the last line with no problems... i added the printStackTrace but still nothing so the method doesn't cause any exceptions

Comment: i changed the navigator from chrome to firefox so when i click on print IDM(Internet Download Manager) wondow pop up to download the file but when i click on download it fails in starting the download, and when i desabled IDM the situation returned as before, nothing happens when i click on print...